# getline C++ not getting result that is required

Tags: c++, getline

Compiler version is 4.2 g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

string a[10];
int i;
int N;
cin>>N;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    getline(cin,a[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

When I input 2 . It asks for input once. When 3 then 2 times . And so on. Please solve. THANKS.

Comment: You will have undefined behavior if `N > 10`, you should change `a` to `vector<string> a(N)`.

Comment: Feast your eyes on the many dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20getline%20skipping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `getline` call reads `end-of-line` character that is still sitting in the input buffer after the N is read.

Consider this as the following input:

```
3 First string
Second string
Third string
```

In your case, the first string is just empty.

If you want to ignore whitespaces after the `N`, write something like

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

(will skip to the end of line), or

```
cin >> N >> std::ws;
```

(will skip all whitespace characters, end of line included).

Comment: So how do I correct it ? What function to use?

Answer (score 0):

After inputting a value for `N`, there is a `\n` (end of line) character left in the buffer. The first getline sees that as the first character, and returns an empty string. Simply do this:

```
string a[10];
int i;
int N;
cin>>N;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);//flush buffer
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    getline(cin,a[i]);
}
```

This will flush the buffer before the `for()` loop.

Comment: This suggests interactive input. Such solution will behave incorrect when stdin is redirected from file.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that when press enter or space it is taking that also as input

```
 #include <iostream>
 include <string>
 using namespace std;
   main()
 {

string a[10];
int i;
 int N;
 cin >> N >> std::ws;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{

getline(cin,a[i]);

}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that actually ASKS for input N times :)

Comment: @Inspired i didn't get u

Comment: I mean this code waits for user input N times as supposed, but a[0] will still contain an empty string.

Comment: @Inspired thnx for u edit i have changed